# Count rows with non-NULL in two columns

Tags: sql, hive, null, hiveql

I am trying to compare two sets in SQL:

```sql
create table my_counts
as select count(*) as total, 
          count(c.cookie) as first,
          count(l.cookie) as second, 
          count(l.cookie and c.cookie) as common
from (select distinct s.cookie from ...) c
full outer join
     (select distinct s.cookie from ...) l
on c.cookie = l.cookie;
select * from my_counts;
```

However, the above fails with this error:

> FAILED: `ClassCastException`
>   `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableStringObjectInspector`
>   cannot be cast to
>   `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.BooleanObjectInspector`

Of course (assuming the SQL statement above does what I think it should do), I should have `total + common = first + second`, so the `common` column is not strictly necessary, but I still wonder if there is a way to count the rows where both columns are non-`NULL`.

Comment: @MaximKorobov There is no need to add the language hint to posts that have the tag [tag:sql], because lang-sql is implied. [see this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting)

Comment: Can you add the table definition and the full stack? This is runtime cast failure and should not happen, I want to verify if it reproes on trunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AND - is a boolean operator. It seems like `cookie` is a string, not boolean.  try to replace `count(l.cookie and c.cookie)`  with this: `count(case when l.cookie is not null and c.cookie is not null then 1 else NULL end) as common`